# How do I translate JavaScript OnClick to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tableau-api

First off, I am totally new to JavaScript so if this is incredibly easy, please forgive my ignorance. I am trying to run a filter using a radio button, that calls a filter in a Tableau worksheet. It works when I try it in on the Tableau JavaScript API examples. But not when I try it on my page and I think it maybe because the new page using JQuery. So how do I translate my function below to JQuery?

```
function showOnly(filterName, values) {
    workbook.activateSheetAsync('SiteTrends').then( onSuccess, onError);
    sheet = viz.getWorkbook().getActiveSheet();
    if(sheet.getSheetType() === 'worksheet') {
        sheet.applyFilterAsync(filterName, values, 'REPLACE');
    } else { 
        worksheetArray = sheet.getWorksheets();
        for(var i = 0; i < worksheetArray.length; i++) {
            worksheetArray[i].applyFilterAsync(filterName, values, 'REPLACE');

      }
   }
}
```

Any help is fully appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: jQuery is a javascript library, so there is no reason including jQuery would make your working javascript code no more working. Your issue is somewhere else... BTW, you should check your console for any error message

Comment: its doest matter using javascript on one page and jquery on other..jquery is javascript library only

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code please? :)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is based on events, and for this reason you have to attach an event to the element.
For example if you have a link with an id called "mylink" you should do something like:

```
$("#mylink").click(function(){ // code of the action when click })
```

For more information about you can take a look at the following links:
the [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) function or the [on('click')](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

And what's the goal of your function ? When does it need to be executed?

Answer (score 0):

Just for more information, you can also use the "on" method to attach it, along with other handlers.

```
     $("#myLink").on("click", function(e){ //your functionality here });
```